# manipulating text file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

text with broken line and dash:

> to validate my solution was
>      I need to take the bench test
>      of the elaborated algorithm
>      only after the table test that
>      the program was implemen-
>      ted this strategy spared
>      development time

code:

```
def file_string():
    with open('speech.txt','r') as file:
        lines = file.read().split("\n")
     string = []
     for line in lines:
         line = line.replace('-\n','')
         string.append(line)
     return (' '.join(string))

print(file_string())
```

Correct output:

> to validate my solution was I need to take the bench test of the elaborated algorithm only after the table test that the program was ***implemented*** this strategy spared development time

Exit from my code:

> to validate my solution was I need to take the bench test of the elaborated algorithm only after the table test that the program was ***implemen- ted*** this strategy spared development time

The text was written in the text editor.

I need this help.

> applying the code sujerido the exit remained:
>
> to validate my solution was  I need to take the bench test  of the elaborated 
>    algorithm  only after the table test that  the program was **implemen ted** this 
>    strategy spared  development time

only happens when I read the file written in a text editor, I need to create a list with these words to make a comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
lines = file.read().split("\n")
```

removes the `'\n'` from your lines because it splits on them. Characters you split on are never part of the results.

So this line

```
line = line.replace('-\n','')
```

can not find anything to replace.

Use `line = line.rstrip("-")` instead, it will remove the `'-'` from the [right end of your string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) if present.

You might benefit from reading/following [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) - to get some tips on how to debug your own program.

Edit:

- You get a ' ' from your `' '-join()`ing of split lines - you need to keep track on which lines ends on `-` and merge it with the following one. Its easier to simply do 2 replaces like this:

---

```
def file_string():
    with open('speech.txt','r') as file:
        lines = file.read()

    return lines.replace('-\n','').replace('\n', ' ') 

print(file_string())
```

to come to your wanted result. Uncomment the commented lines and remove the `lines = """..."""`.

Comment: hello patrick, I modified the code but got a space between the word.(implemen  ted).

Comment: @Bruno - you are right.  I propose a different solution that first replaces `'-\n'` by nothing  and then `'\n'` by `' '` to get to the desired output.

Comment: the problem occurs when I read from a text file, the word continues with the space, I do not know but what I do.

Comment: @Bruno the edited version still gives you wrong output?

Comment: Yes @patrick , I do not know but what I do, this happens when I read the text file edited in notpad.

Comment: @Bruno Edit your quedtion. Add the output you get when you apply my proposed solution and what you want to get.

Answer (score 1):

This will do (updated)?

```
import re

def file_string():
    with open('speech.txt','r') as file:
        lines = file.read()
    lstr = re.sub(r'\-[\n]*',r'',lines)
    lstr = re.sub(r'[\n]+',r' ',lstr)
    return lstr

print(file_string())
```

Comment: The text was created in a text editor, there is some possibility that it is giving error for this reason

Comment: Friends many excuses, the mistake is that I was copying the text from a pdf and pasting it into the text editor. All codes are correct and working.